# Certificate Autority to Ethereum

Tags: solidity, dapps

Since there is no native support to Certificate Authorities in Ethereum, what are good ways to emulate it in a permission network (we are using Hyperledger Besu)?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a permissioned network it's not really decentralized; you control it. And as you control the network you can, at least indirectly, control what happens in it.

I guess this depends on your network settings. If you are limiting who can write to the network (generate blocks) then you can establish certain rules and only allow those to write who follow these rules. Then your rules may include stuff similar to what certificate authorities do.

On the other hand you don't need any functionality like certificate authority. You *are* the certificate authority since you control the network.

The details depend on your network configuration and your exact needs but the big picture is the same: your network, your rules.